# AngularJS select item on array

Tags: angularjs, json, intel, intel-xdk

I´m stuck in something that seems to be quite easy, but I can´t find the way to go.

I´m developing an hybrid mobile app in AngularJS with Intel XDK, and I have to show a array of results from JSON, and allow users to click on one of them to get further info. I need to show the list on page A, and the complete info on page B.

By now I´ve done all but showing the full info on page B, even if I managed to get the ID of the item clicked. What I have is

Controller.js

```
.controller('myController', function($scope,$http) {  

//This to get de JSON
$http({ method: 'GET',
    url: '/lib/myData.json'
    }).then(function successCallback(response) {
        $scope.misDatos = response.data;

      }, function errorCallback(response) {
        console.error ("no json data");
      });

//This to get the item clicked
$scope.setMaster = function(section) {

    $scope.selected = section;
    console.log("Item Clicked: " + $scope.selected.id);        

};    

})
```

PageA.html

```
<div class="card" ng-repeat="dato in misDatos" ng-click="setMaster(dato)" >

      <div class="item item-divider">
        {{dato.objetivo}}
      </div>

      <div class="item item-text-wrap">
          <p>{{dato.descripcion}}...</p>

      </div>

      <div class="item item-divider">
       <a href="#/app/playlists/"></i> Más información</a>
      </div>

</div>
```

PageB.html

```
 <div class="list card" ng-repeat="dato in misDatos | filter: {id:selected}">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
      <h4>{{dato.objetivo}}</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <p>{{dato.descripcion}}</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

In my console I can see the correct ID clicked on page A

```
Item Clicked:3
```

But i can´t make my "B" page to show the data from the result selected...

Do you know what am I doing wrong? Is there a nice tutorial to do so?

Thanks everyone in advance!

Answer (score 0):

In page B, you should be binding to the value of the selected item as below

```
<div class="list card">

  <div class="item item-avatar">
    <h4>{{selected.objetivo}}</h4>
  </div>

  <div class="item">
   <p>{{selected.descripcion}}</p>
  </div>


</div>
```

This is because the value of the selected item is now bound to the `scope` through `$scope.selected`

Comment: Thanks for your answer Evans! Unfortunately it doesn´t work... I understand the first line on your code should be "<div class="list card" ng-repeat="dato in misDatos | filter: {id:selected}">", being "selected" the data i´ve gotten in the controller, correct?

Comment: We do not need the repeater as the value of the `$scope.selected` is the actual object. So the first line is as in the code above

Comment: Just seen sth. Please show the code for the `controllers` for both pages.

Comment: Is the same controller for both pages... Should I split it, and create a different controller for page B? I´ve checked on the console when loading B page, and it shows correctly the whole data for the clicked object, but for some reason, it doesn´t write on the page...

Comment: Could you please show the code for wiring up the controller to the view of B?
Ideally each view should have it's controller

Comment: I´ve split the controller for the two pages; now the call to the controller on page B is done like this: "<ion-view myTitle" ng-controller="myOtherController">"

Comment: The reason is that the value of $scope.selected is in the controller of `A` and is not available in controller of `B`. 
PS-Are you using `ui-router`?

Comment: No, i´m not using it (actually, I don´t know what´s for... ). Is it that complex?? I thought it would something like "item.php?id={{mydata.id}}"!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I did it. This is how it works for me; wish it could help someone, bcos I spent the whole with this issue.

The problem, as Evans said, was that there was no data available on "page B", so the solution is to send the info to that page. I´ve used the reference of http://excellencenodejsblog.com/angularjs-sharing-data-between-controller/, placing the factory on the "app.js" file, and the controllers on the "controllers.js" file.

Cheers!